# The state of being integrated

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I am looking for a noun of the adjective "integrated", as in, "combining or coordinating separate elements so as to provide a harmonious, interrelated whole."

Integration describes the process that produces this state, rather than the actual state (I think).

Integratedness works but it is a bit clunky and not that widely used.

Example:

> The individual parts of the mechanical clock interact with each other and work together to keep track of time. The mechanical clock has high [word I'm looking for].

Comment: ***integration***

Comment: I think you've got the answer in the question. The end state of the integration of parts is a "whole".

Comment: Hmm, may be wholeness?

Comment: There are a number of ways of expressing what you want but they all need context. For Single Word Requests you are supposed to supply a sentence into which to insert the word for this very reason. 'Whole', 'construct', 'creation' and many more will fit, but you need to supply context.

Comment: Choice of term can depend on how it is used. Please [edit] to supply some texts (sentences, short paragraphs) to show how you intend to use the term.

Comment: @NigelJ and Lawrence thank you, I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "interdependent"?

The adjective interdependence is defined as a) "the fact of depending on each other" (Cambridge online dictionary) as well as b) "a logical or natural association between two or more things."

For instance, "The interdependence of motion and force was not indeed formulated into definite laws by Galileo, but his writings on dynamics are everywhere suggestive of those laws, and his solutions of dynamical problems involve their recognition."

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is ***cohesion*** or ***cohesiveness***

[Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cohesion) defines *cohesion* as:

> The action or fact of forming a united whole.
>   *‘They lacked cohesion and, for the most part, played as 15 individuals rather than a single unit.’*

And [*cohesiveness*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cohesiveness) as:

> The quality of forming a united whole.
>   *‘There is a lack of community cohesiveness, and the people are generally more focused on immediate and individual economic needs.’*

In your example:

> The individual parts of the mechanical clock interact with each other and work together to keep track of time. The mechanical clock has high ***cohesion***.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **organized**. [Here is the (paywalled) Oxford English Dictionary entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132457):

> Formed into a structured whole; systematically ordered and arranged; having a formal organizational structure to arrange, coordinate, and carry out activities; spec. having formed into a union, political party, or similar body. Cf. organized labour n. at Special uses.

The parts or organs are integrated into the whole, so the resulting whole is *organized*.